# Writing multiple entries from a single message in Kafka Connect

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

If on one topic I receive messages in some format which represent a list of identical structs (e.g. a JSON list or a repeated field in protobuf) could I configure Kafka Connect to write each entry in the list as a separate row (say in a parquet file in HDFS, or in a SQL database)? Is this possible using only the bundled converters/connectors?

I.e. can I use each Kafka message to represent thousands of records, rather than sending thousands of individual messages?

What would be a straightforward way to achieve this with Kafka Connect?

Comment: You can use Kafka Streams for this. Kafka streams are capable to transform messages from one source  topic into another destination topic. And then use Kafka Connect to read messages from destination topic instead of source topic.

Answer (score 0):

The bundled message transforms are only capable of making one-to-one message manipulations. Therefore, you would have to explicitly produce those flattened lists in some way (directly, or via a stream processing application) if you wanted Connect to write it out as separate records.

Or, if applicable, you can use Hive or Spark to expand that list as well for later processing.